# jQuery .val() on multiple select, don't comma separate?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multi-select as so:

```
<select id="filter-cardset" data-placeholder="Select a Card Set" multiple="multiple">
<option>Metal Raiders</option>
<option>Abyss Rising</option>
<option>Shonen, Vol 1</option>
<option>Shonen, Vol2</option>
</select>
```

I use jQuery to get the value:

```
var selection = jQuery("#filter-cardset").val();
```

Which results in an array like so:

```
["Metal Raiders", "Shonen, Vol2"]
```

I then send this to an API:

```
myapi.com/info.php?selection=Metal Raiders, Shonen, Vol2
```

Which is sent like so:

```
if(selection !=""){ apiurl+= "&selection="+encodeURIComponent(selection); }
```

So as you can see, the issue is the comma in the option value. My API can separate them by ";" symbol.

```
metal raiders;shonen,vol2
```

However I can't seem to send this via URL as it always comma separates the values. Any idea?

Comment: You can try `selection.join(";")`, this will convert the array into a string with the specified separator `;`. example `["Metal Raiders", "Shonen, Vol2"].join(";")` will result to `"Metal Raiders;Shonen, Vol2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on API accepted pattern do:

```
var selection = jQuery("#filter-cardset").val().join(';');
```